# Analysis of randomized algorithms

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, sorting, randomized-algorithms, quicksort

The expected running time, $T(n)$, of quicksort when the pivot is chosen uniformly at random satisfies $$ T(n) \leq \mathcal O(n) +\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}(T(i) + T(n - i)),$$
which leads to the known bound of $\mathcal O (n \log n)$.

Suppose we consider the following procedure to discard bad pivots: after sampling a random pivot, sample uniformly $\log n$ elements from the input array and compare them to the pivot, if the pivot lies in the middle third of the array of $\log n$ sampled elements proceed with quicksort as normal, otherwise sample again a new pivot and $\log n$ elements from the array.

I want to find the new recurrence relation for $T(n)$. My intuition says that it should be

$$ T(n) \leq \underbrace{\mathcal O(\log n)}_{\text{time to compare the pivot with $\log n$ elements}} + \underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}_{\text{probability of resampling}} \cdot \mathcal O(\log n) + \underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{3} \right)}_{\text{probability of not resampling}}\cdot(\mathcal O(n) + \frac{1}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}(T(i) + T(n - i))).$$

Is this correct?

Comment: $\frac23\log n$ and $1-\frac23\log n$ cannot be probabilities, because $\log n$ is not bound when $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Also you cannot bound the complexity, as you could theoretically be unlucky each time and never pick a satisfying pivot and sample and loop forever, so you should consider the expected value of the complexity.

Comment: @Nathaniel: So how can I bound the expected running time? I thought that the terms coming after $\mathcal O(\log n)$ would take care of the average of the two possible cases: resampling and not resampling.